# A duplicate field name "StartDate" was found in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

You cannot vote on your own post 
0

After completion of Migration from SharePoint 2010 to SP2013, didn’t see any timer jobs under Job Definition. So we have deactivated the feature and activated at SiteCollection Level then able to see the Custom Timer Job Under Timer Job Definition, Except One Custom Timer Job for that we have deactivated and while activating the feature at web level getting the error A duplicate field name "StartDate" was found in SharePoint 2013.

In SharePoint 2010 there is no issue, but after migration to SharePoint 2013 getting A duplicate field name "StartDate" was found.

We have two Custom List Definitions (Activity Taks and Workflow Task) created the StartDate Column using below field attributes in Schema.xml
[image]

And also have many custom ContentTypes referred the StartDate columns like below mentioned in the Elments.xml file

[image]

This StartDate Field had used in the code in many places. Can you please help on this issue how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is an internal name that you have used for the SharePoint column that has been reserved in the SharePoint System.

Change the Name property "StartDate" to something unique, not a built-in field name.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-duplicate-field-name-was-found-after-upgrading-your-sharepoint-2010-solutions/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/22da8c/sharepoint-server-2013-a-duplicate-field-name-xxx-was-fou/